# What's the meaning of "to" in "Love you to"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, syntactic-analysis, infinitives

There's a Beatles song called "Love You To" (not To Love You nor Love You Too). I've never understood this grammar construction and I don't understand what the title actually means. Is it just a poetry resource to say "To Love You"? Or does putting the "to" at the ens of a sentence change its meaning somehow? Maybe is it a way to emphasize? Are there other examples of putting "to" at the end? Thank you.

Comment: Get the context, get the meaning. Good Luck.

Comment: "Would you like me to dance?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shows there is an implied ending that the listener already understands. For example, if I said, "Would you like me to give you a ride to the airport," you might respond, "I'd love you to" or maybe just "Love you to." I know that you'd love me to ... take you to the airport.
As for what the title means, well, you'll have to figure out what the Beatles would love you to do.

Comment: Oh, it's very clear now, thank you! So dumb I didn't see it!

Answer (score -2):

I believe it is saying I love you also as in too.  That is a very old song and I don't think that  they were worried about to or too back then.

Comment: No, that it not what it means. And the distinction between _to_ and _too_ was somewhat more fastidiously upheld back then than it is now that textspeak and general online typing has come along.